# Cannot SSH -T git@github.com

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have been trying to connect GitHub using SSH(git clone) on my PC(Ubuntu 20.04).

```
0. Installed SSH, git
1. Created SSH-key under ~/.SSH/
2. Submit my id_rsa.pub key to GitHub
3. SSH -T git@github.com <- Did not work
4. SSH -vT git@github.com <- Didn't work
6. SSH git@github.com <- It worked
7. git clone ~ <- Did not work
```

When I executed SSH -T git@github.com, it did not work.

```
Error Messages:
Connection to github.com closed by remote host.

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Terminal showed "Connection to github.com closed by remote host"

But when I tried SSH git@github.com, it worked and terminal showed Hi, username =.

Then I tried git clone (my GitHub repository), but terminal said that "Please make sure you have right access~".

What is the problem with my SSH connection?

Comment: Can you please copy and paste the exact error message you got from `git clone` into your question as a text block?

Comment: Connection to github.com closed by remote host.

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

Answer (score 0):

Note (for other readers) that the path is case-sensitive (unless you are on Windows), which means the SSH keys are under `~/.ssh`, not `~/.SSH`

And the URL should be:

```
git clone git@github.com:<user>/<reponame>
```

Again, case sensitive: double-check the URL of the remote repository.

Comment: Stack overflow doesn't allow to post article with ssh, so I changed all ssh to SSH. All above have been done.And it doesn't work.

Comment: @ekusiadadus What is the URL you are using?

Comment: @ekusiadadus OK can you copy the exact got clone command you are using, with one of those URLs?

Comment: git clone git@github.com:scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git